# SQL SERVER - Group records by n minutes interval

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this:

```
     [SDate - DateTime]              [Value - Decimal]
    2010-11-16 10:32:22                     1
    2010-11-16 10:58:08                     2
```

and I need a query to group records by n minutes interval.

Output can be for example(grouped by 60 minutes):

```
    2010-11-16 10:10:00   avg(Value)
    2010-11-16 10:11:00   avg(Value)
    2010-11-16 10:12:00   avg(Value)
```

Up to now, I have been using this query to group by 10 minutes interval because intervals were between 0 and 60 minutes:

```
...
GROUP BY
DATEPART(YEAR, SDate),
DATEPART(MONTH, SDate),
DATEPART(DAY, SDate),
DATEPART(HOUR, SDate),
(DATEPART(MINUTE, SDate) / 10)
```

But now the interval can be **125436758** minutes, for example.

I can not create new tables and the user-defined interval must be n minutes.
I am using SQL SERVER 2012. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GROUP BY 
...
(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, SDate) / @n)
```

Comment: It works, but how can I get an output like 2010-11-16 10:10:00? Thanks

Comment: Look at the different output options of the FORMAT() function.

Comment: Consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814930/group-datetime-into-5-15-30-and-60-minute-intervals) answer if you need to format the n-minutes period as a date in the output