# Group records by every n minutes datetime range based on Min(date) in each group in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, grouping, intervals

I have these sample records in my table, I want to group them by every 3 minutes.based on min(Matched_BeginTime) on each group.

```
Keywords    Matched_BeginTime        Station_ID       Program_ID    TVCapCID    ScheduleID
"Police"    2015-11-17 17:00:37.160   120           715             486290066   102691
"Police"    2015-11-17 17:01:48.620   120           715             486290088   102691
"Police"    2015-11-17 17:02:02.140   120           715             486290091   102691
"Police"    2015-11-17 17:02:53.100   120           715             486290102   102691
"Police"    2015-11-17 17:03:03.540   120           715             486290106   102691
"Police"    2015-11-17 17:03:48.020   120           715             486290119   102691
"SAS"       2015-11-17 17:03:57.940   120           715             486290122   102691
"SAS"       2015-11-17 17:08:25.800   120           715             486290197   102691
"Police"    2015-11-17 17:08:32.960   120           715             486290199   102691
"Emergency" 2015-11-17 17:09:02.540   120           715             486290206   102691
"SAS"       2015-11-17 17:10:55.640   120           715             486290246   102691
"Police"    2015-11-17 17:12:23.240   120           715             486290273   102691
```

this is my ideal result:

```
Keywords_Groups         Min_Matched_BeginTime   
Police                  11/17/2015 17:00:37     
Police,SES              11/17/2015 17:03:48      
SES,Police,Emergency    11/17/2015 17:08:26      
Police                  11/17/2015 17:12:23
```

Each record is grouped by matched_Date in every 3 minutes .
forexp , first 5 records should be in one group because theyre in range of `min(matchDate)+ 3minutes`

> Note : I tried to use the solutions given before. like these ones:
>   [How to group time by hour or by 10 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002661/how-to-group-time-by-hour-or-by-10-minutes)
>
> [SQL SERVER - Group records by n minutes interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788729/sql-server-group-records-by-n-minutes-interval)
>
> this is the sample code I tried from above solutions:

```
select datepart(minute, Matched_BeginTime)/3,min(Matched_BeginTime),Keywords
from [table]
group by datepart(minute, Matched_BeginTime)/3,Keywords
order by MIN(Matched_BeginTime)
```

and This is the result :

```
0   2015-11-17 17:00:37.160 "Police" 
1   2015-11-17 17:03:03.540 "Police" 
1   2015-11-17 17:03:57.940 "SAS" 
2   2015-11-17 17:08:25.800 "SAS" 
2   2015-11-17 17:08:32.960 "Police" 
3   2015-11-17 17:09:02.540 "Emergency" 
3   2015-11-17 17:10:55.640 "SAS" 
4   2015-11-17 17:12:23.240 "Police"
```

As you can see, it grouped by minutes division by 3 , started from 00 but not based on Min(Matched_BeginTime)

Thank you for any help

> Note:By using Stored Procedure, I can do it fine, I prefer to have a
>   single TSQL command for that.

Comment: How do you want to "roll-up" your Station ID's and Program ID's though? For example, could there ever be a situation where there are different ID's within a 3 minute period? If so, how should these be displayed?

Comment: @TheShaman No , actually they can be ignored. I've removed them from the result

Comment: You can use a sub query to get the min timestamp and use datediff to find minutes and divide by 3 as above.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: @Hogan thanks for the tip. I tried that, but I cant use aggregate function on group . how can I use it ? could you please write a sample about what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use a sub query to get the min timestamp and use datediff to
>   find minutes and divide by 3 as above.
>   msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Sub query to get min timestamp

```
Select min(Matched_BeginTime) as minMBT FROM [table]
```

Add that into you query and use datediff:

```
select datediff(minute, sub.minMBT, Matched_BeginTime)/3,Keywords
from [table], (Select min(Matched_BeginTime) as minMBT FROM [table]) as Sub
group by datediff(minute, sub.minMBT, Matched_BeginTime)/3,Keywords
order by datediff(minute, sub.minMBT, Matched_BeginTime)/3
```

> **note**:
>   Adding this sub-query to the from line with no where is the same
>   as a "cross join" or a regular join with no on clause -- since sub
>   just has one row and one column it just adds that single value to each row.

If you want to have multiple rows "joined" with a comma you can use the technique I show here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1785923/215752

However, if you have a front end used for display I expect creating the comma separated list there is easier.