# How to group timestamps in a 10 minute bucket and aggregate

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a column "hit_timestamp" with time stamp datatype.
below are some of the values.

```
20-MAR-17 00.00.00.000000000
20-MAR-17 00.03.53.000000000
20-MAR-17 00.01.16.000000000
20-MAR-17 00.07.32.000000000
20-MAR-17 00.18.36.000000000
20-MAR-17 00.16.12.000000000
```

I want to group then in 10 minutes buckets

```
time_bucket        no_of_records
----------          ---------
"000000_000010"     4
"000011_000020"     2
```

Comment: Before jumping to writing code of any kind, you need to spend some time thinking about the difference between "discrete" values (such as counting people in a room) and "continuous" ones (such as time). Specifically in your time_bucket descriptions, where will you fit an event that happens at 00.10.23? It is neither between 0 and 10 nor between 11 and 20. You may write the greatest code in the world, if you get this wrong your results will be wrong anyway.

Comment: Please Edit your post again and pay attention to tags. Are you really using all of MySQL, SQL Server, and Oracle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL SERVER - Group records by n minutes interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788729/sql-server-group-records-by-n-minutes-interval)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 10 minute intervals, the easiest way to proceed is to get the string format of your date, and remove anything at the right of the first digit of the 2-digit minute part. So `20-03-17 00.18.36` would be stripped to `20-03-17 00.1`. That would work well as the value to group by. For displaying purposes you could then add `0.00` to it for denoting the lower bound of the bucket, and `9.59` for the higher bound.

Now the function to convert a timestamp to a string is different in different database engines.

For Oracle it would look like this:

```
select   substr(to_char(dat, 'YY-MM-DD HH24.MI'), 1, 13) || '0.00' bucket_start,
         substr(to_char(dat, 'YY-MM-DD HH24.MI'), 1, 13) || '9.59' bucket_end,
         count(*)
from     mytable
group by substr(to_char(dat, 'YY-MM-DD HH24.MI'), 1, 13)
order by 1
```

Output:

```
   BUCKET_START   |    BUCKET_END     | COUNT(*)
------------------+-------------------+---------
17-03-20 00.00.00 | 17-03-20 00.09.59 |    4
17-03-20 00.10.00 | 17-03-20 00.19.59 |    2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can round down hti_teimstamp to an interval of every 10 minutes, then do a group by.

> "2017-03-20 00:03:53.0000000" becomes "2017-03-20 00:00:00.000"
>
> "2017-03-20 00:18:36.0000000" becomes "2017-03-20 00:10:00.000"

```
select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, hit_timestamp)/10*10 ,0) as time_bucket, count(1) as no_of_records
from #temp
group by dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, hit_timestamp)/10*10 ,0)
```