# Count aggregated data on every nth hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some data generated during time. I used the query below to count the number of "interactions" which happened every hour.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Quantity, FORMAT(cast(InteractionDate as datetime2), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH')  as Datum
FROM Interaction as in
INNER JOIN Mission as mi
on in.MissionID=mi.MissionID
WHERE InteractionDate between '2015-01-13 12' AND '2015-01-22 12'
GROUP BY FORMAT(cast(InteractionDate as datetime2), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH') 
ORDER BY Datum
```

The query above gives me this:

```
116 | 2015-01-15 00 
37  | 2015-01-15 01  
17  | 2015-01-15 02
```

Now i want to get the aggregated number of interactions on every nth hour. Let's say I want every 3rd hour, for the data provided I would get:

```
170 | 2015-01-15 02
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "aggregated number of interactions on every nth hour"?  Sample data and desired results are always helpful.

Comment: I edited the question, hope it clarified the situation a bit

Answer (score 0):

You could group by date and hour separately, this would let you have hour-expressions. For example;

```
GROUP BY cast(InteractionDate as date), (hour(InteractionDate)/4)
```

This would give you midnight to 6am in the first bucket, 6am to midday in the next etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate data by any period of time by getting the interval using datediff, and then making the integer division, like this:

```
group by datediff(hour, '1990-01-01T00:00:00', yourDatetime) / 3
```

The maths are: get the integer number of hours from the base date, and make an integer division by 3, what yields groups of 3 consecutive hours with the same result. And then it's use to group the data.

This wil get the number of hours from the base date-time that you want to specify. The only important part, in this case, is the time part, which let you decide the inital point for the 3 hour intervals. In this case, the intervals are `[00:00 to 03:00]`, `[03:00 to 06:00]` and so on. If you need different intervals, make a different base date-time, for example `'1990-01-01T00:01:00'` would give you the intervals `[01:00 to 04:00]`, `[04:00 to 07:00]`, and so on.

To get further details, see this full answer: [Group DateTime into 5,15,30 and 60 minute intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814930/group-datetime-into-5-15-30-and-60-minute-intervals/9814970#9814970)

In this answer you'll see how you can show the start and end date-time of each interval, apart from the aggregated values. And have a deeper insight into this solution.