# Sql: how to get how many records are inserted each X minutes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know how many records are inserted in a table, each X minutes.

My table has a structure like this:

```
ID ; Date (a DateTime field) ; Others fields
```

So, for instance, how can I get how many records are inserted each 5 minutes, starting from a date( 2022-08-04, time : 08:00:00)  ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a column in this table with a timestamp of when the record was inserted?

Comment: Date field is a DATETIME field

Comment: Gotcha. Check out some of the answers at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814930/group-datetime-into-5-15-30-and-60-minute-intervals) where there are a few solutions to bucket records into 5 minute periods and aggregate.